# How can I find the IP addresses of an AWS RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an RDS instance on AWS running MySQL.  "Public availability" is set to "yes", and I can connect using the endpoint dns name.

Using the AWS console, how can I find both the public and private IP addresses of the instance?

Comment: Why do you want your mysql accessable remotely - sounds like a problem waiting to happen??

Comment: How else would I access it?  From time to time I need to investigate tables using MySql Workbench.

Comment: Try SSH Port forwarding [so you don't need to expose the relatively insecure DB connection]

Answer (score 1):

There is only endpoint for RDS. Public and Private IP address might change if there is failover happen. You may refer to this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInstanceinaVPC.html#USER_VPC.Subnets).

You may use `nslookup` command to look for the IP address, you will get public IP address if it's outside of VPC and private IP address if it's within the same VPC as your RDS.

Answer (score 1):

```
EC2 > Network Interfaces
```

Then look for your `RDSNetworkInterface` - usually identifiable by the security group. It will list the Public and Private IP there.